# Date_parameter input are date and time and only date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have following procedure where date_parameter input are date and time,
and I only need date for date_parameter input, how can I make it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Month_Sub1 (
Month_Sub1_cursor IN OUT Reports.rep_type,
date_parameter IN system_days.daytime%TYPE)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN Month_Sub1_cursor FOR
```

thanks,
S

Comment: You can't. Oracle does not have a data type that only stores the date.

Comment: Can I convert this "system_days.daytime"  to date only? Convert in "date_parameter IN system_days.daytime%TYPE".

Comment: Hi Joe, in oracle  you can consider **DATE** as a float number which has two parts [part1: Days added to base calendar].[part2: portion of day to seconds]. so if you truncate a date you will get 00:00:00 of the day in date,  so trunc of a date is also a date, you can use **TO_CHAR** to get your exact portion. EX: **TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')** is 2017-01-31

Answer (score 2):

You could just [`trunc`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions236.htm) it to get the date part:

```
date_parameter := TRUNC(date_parameter)
```

Comment: I need to define it in procedure in "date_parameter IN system_days.daytime%TYPE", can I use something like "date_parameter IN system_days.day%TYPE"

Comment: @JoeGreen just add this line to the procedure's body before you need to use `date_parameter`.

Comment: `trunc()` doesn't return "the date part". It returns a date with the time set to `00:00:00`

Comment: That's how I understood the requirement. Perhaps the OP could clarify what exactly he's trying to do?

Comment: This procedure used in Crystal Report and "date_parameter IN system_days.daytime%TYPE" prompts date and time in Crystal and I need only date so trying to fix it from procedure side.

Comment: What is the real underlying type of `system_days.daytime`?

Comment: You can't modify an `in` parameter. You'd have to define a local variable and assign it to `trunc(date_parameter)`.